# PHP like $$var in T-SQL (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any way to execute something like php `$$var` ..?

Which will make the value of a var as var name.

I have been googling for many hours ant cant find any that satisfy my needs.

Thanks.

edit:

currently what I want to achieve is something similar to this

```
declare @table1 table(Name Varchar(100))
declare @table2 table(Name Varchar(100))
...
declare @table10 table(Name Varchar(100))

declare @int1 int
set @int1 = 0
while @int1 < 10
begin
select @[table + @int1]
END
```

Comment: No, there is no equivalent in T-SQL. It might be possible to achieve a similar effect with dynamic SQL but that is likely to be problematic because of issues of variable scope. Please consider updating your question with some details about the problem you hope to solve - it's likely that there's an alternative solution.

Comment: hi @EdHarper thanks......and i have added something I want to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the example in the question isn't valid T-SQL, it's not clear whether you want to select the value of `@[table + @int1]`, or from the table (i.e. `select name from @[table + @int1]`) - I'm assuming here that it's the second one.

One approach would be to have a single table with an indicator column classifying the rows:

```
declare @table table(Name Varchar(100), groupid int)
...

declare @int1 int
set @int1 = 0
while @int1 < 10
begin
  select name from @table WHERE groupid = @int1
  set @int1 = @int1 + 1
end
```